# Understanding script language

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a newbie to scripting languages trying to learn bash programming.

I have very basic question. Suppose I want to create three folders like `$HOME/folder/`
with two child folders `folder1` and `folder2`.

1. If I execute command in shell like

   ```
   mkdir -p $HOME/folder/{folder1,folder2}
   ```

   folder will be created along with child folder.
2. If the same thing is executed through script I'm not able get expected result. If `sample.sh` contains

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   mkdir -p $HOME/folder/{folder1,folder2}
   ```

   and I execute `sh ./sample.sh`, the first folder will be created then in that a single `{folder1,folder2}` directory is created. The separate child folders are not created.

My query is

1. How the script file works when we compared to as terminal command? i.e., why is it not the same?
2. How to make it work?

Comment: before voting down please pass the comment why you voting down

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112031/difference-between-korn-and-bash-shell/19112167#19112167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace expansion doesn't happen in sh.

In sh:

```
$ echo {1,2}
```

produces

```
{1,2}
```

In bash:

```
$ echo {1,2}
```

produces

```
1 2
```

Execute your script using `bash` instead of using `sh` and you should see expected results.

Comment: It depends on what `sh` is.  Sometimes it actually will be Bash.  :)

Comment: @vinayhunachyal note that it is `#!/bin/bash` <--- there is a `!`.

Comment: Sorry while commenting i missed but in my code i have included `!`still im getting same output

Comment: Is `/bin/bash` the path of your `bash`? Check it with `which bash`.

Comment: @vinayhunachyal If you're executing your script by saying `sh ./sample.sh`, it implies that you're using `sh`.  Execute it by saying `bash ./sample.sh` or even `./sample.sh` **if** you're running `bash`.

Comment: Ya i checked its in `/bin/bash` and which bash `/bin/bash`

Comment: @devnull Thank you its worked .. How to make it work with sh since if i have only sh

Comment: @vinayhunachyal As mentioned above, *brace expansion* wouldn't happen in `sh`.

Comment: @devnull then its not possible to create child folder using sh shell?

Comment: @vinayhunachyal you can do `mkdir -p foo/bar/baz` in sh, but not `mkdir -p foo/{bar,baz}`, i.e. the latter wouldn't *expand* to subdirectories `bar` and `baz`.

Comment: @devnull but it wont create two subdirectoy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38542/discussion-between-devnull-and-vinay-hunachyal)

Answer (score 2):

`bash` behaves differently when invoked as `sh`, to more closely mimic the POSIX standard. One of the things that changes is that brace expansion (which is absent from POSIX) is no longer recognized. You have several options:

1. Run your script using `bash ./sample.sh`. This ignores the hashbang and explicitly uses `bash` to run the script.
2. Change the hashbang to read `#!/bin/bash`, which allows you to run the script by itself (assuming you set its execute bit with `chmod +x sample.sh`).

   Note that running it as `sh ./sample.sh` would still fail, since the hashbang is only used when running the file itself as the executable.
3. Don't use brace expansion in your script. You could still use as a longer method for avoiding duplicate code:

   ```
   for d in folder1 folder2; do
       mkdir -p "$HOME/folder/$d"
   done
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because while your tags indicate you think you are using Bash, you may not be.  This is because of the very first line:

```
#/bin/sh
```

That says "use the system default shell."  That may not be bash.  Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Oh, and note that you were missing the ! after #.  I'm not sure if that's just a copy-paste error here, but you need the !.

Comment: while writing here i missed but its there in my script file !

Comment: I didn't downvote, but changing the hashbang will have no effect when the script is run using `sh ./sample.sh`.